# Equivalent of std::deque at in tbb::concurrent_queue container?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, tbb

I am using std::deque **at** function to access elements without popping from the queue since i am using the same queue in different iterations. My solution is based on coarse-grained multithreading. Now i wanted to make it fine-grained multithreading solution. For that, i am using tbb::concurrent_queue. But i need the equivalent function of std::deque **at** operation in tbb::concurrent_queue?

***EDIT***
This is how i am implementing with std::deque (coarse-grained multithreading)
Keep in mind that dq is static queue(i.e. using many times in different iterations)

```
vertext_found = true;
std::deque<T> dq;
while ( i < dq->size())
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&h);
    if( i < dq.size() ) 
    {
          v = dq.at(i);      // accessing element of queue without popping
          i++;
          vertext_found = true;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&h);
    if (vertext_found && (i < dq.size()) && v != NULL)
    {
          **operation on 'v'
          vertext_found = false;
    }
}
```

I want to achieve the same result with tbb::concurrent_queue?

Answer (score 1):

If your algorithm has separate passes that fill the queue or consume the queue, consider using tbb::concurrent_vector.  It has a push_back method that could be used for the fill pass, and an at() method for the consumption passes.  If threads contend to pop elements in a consumption pass, consider using a tbb::atomic counter to generate indices for at().

If there is no such clean separation of filling and consuming, using at() would probably create more problems than it solves, even if it existed, because it would be racing against a consumer.

If a consumption pass just needs to loop over the concurrent_vector in parallel, consider using tbb::parallel_for for the loop.  tbb::concurrent_vector has a range() method that supports this idiom.

```
void consume( tbb::concurrent_vector<T>& vec ) {
    tbb::parallel_for( vec.range(), [&]( const tbb::concurrent_vector<T>::range_type& r ) {
        for( auto i=r.begin(); i!=r.end(); ++i ) {
            T value = *i;
            ...process value...;
        }
    });
}
```

If a consumption pass cannnot use tbb:parallel_for, consider using a TBB atomic counter to generate the indices.  Initialize the counter to zero and use ++ to increment it.  Here is an example:

```
tbb::atomic<size_t> head;
tbb::concurrent_vector<T> vec;

bool pop_one( T& result ) { // Try to grab next item from vec
    size_t i = head++;      // Fetch-and-increment must be single atomic operation
    if( i<vec.size() ) {
        result = vec[i];
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;       // Failed
    }
}
```

In general, this solution will be less scalable than using tbb::parallel_for, because the counter "head" introduces a point of contention in the memory system.

Comment: It doesn't have separate phases.. Filling the queue is one time operation.. Then that queue will be consumed by 8 threads.. But the same queue is accessed many times(iterations).. So if i pop the elements, then i have to fill the queue again which will be overhead. For that, i am accessing the elements with at operation, which is not available in tbb::concurrent_queue. I edited my post and included code for std::deque. Please check and suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doxygen docs in the TBB site ([TBB Doxy docs](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/doxygen/)) there's no operation `at` in the queue. You can `push` and `try_pop` elements with a `tbb::strict_ppl::concurrent_queue`.

If you're using a `tbb::deprecated::concurrent_queue` (older versions of TBB), there are available the `push_if_not_full` and `pop_if_present` operations.

In both queues, "multiple threads may each push and pop concurrently" as stated down in the brief section.

Comment: There's also the `tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue`, but it has no `at` method neither. The only TBB container that seems to have `at` is `tbb::concurrent_vector`.

Comment: Yes i know push and try_pop are available. But that will modify the queue and hence the performance decreases. I can't access elements of concurrent_queue without pop operation?